# Переполнение int в java

Tags: java

Есть код

```
int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int b = 5000;
int c = 123;
int min = Math.min(a, Math.min(b,c));
int max = Math.max(a, Math.max(b,c));
int d = a + b + c - min - max;
```

Почему в переменной d сохраняется правильное значение ( `b` )?

Ведь когда мы делаем `a + b` ( `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 5000`) у нас будет переполнение `int'a`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Да нет, все правильно. Вместе с переполнениями так и получается.

Рассчитаем по шагам:

```
int step1 = a+b+c;
System.out.println(step1);
int step2 = step1-min;
System.out.println(step2);
int d = step2 - max;
System.out.println(d);
```

Выводится:

```
-2147478526
-2147478649
5000
```

Просто на последнем шаге происходит второе переполнение `-2147478649 -2147483647` и получается `5000`.

**P.S.** Вообще, наличие переполнения не влияет на [ассоциативность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) операции сложения. В Java сложение значений одного целого типа всегда ассоциативно, о чем упомянуто в спецификации ([§JLS 15.18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)):

> Integer addition is associative when the operands are all of the same type.

Соответственно, для любых `a` и `b` значение `a + b - b` будет равно `a`.

Из этого следует, что в Вашем случае `d` всегда будет равно среднему по величине из трех чисел (`a`, `b` и `c`) независимо от их значений.

Answer (score 4):

грубо говоря возьмём более простой восьмибитный тип: [-127; 128] - диапазон значений.
если к 128 + 1 в восьмибитной переменной - получится -127.
так и у вас:
int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int b = a + 5000;

тут b будет равно Integer.MIN_VALUE + 4999, т.к. произошло переполнение.