# Какая особенность вычисления переполнения промежуточных значений в Java?

Tags: java

```
int a = 2_000_000_000;
int b = 2_000_000_000;
System.out.println(a+b - b);
System.out.println((a+b)/2 );
```

Output:

```
  2000000000
 -147483648
```

Comment: А в чём вы видите какую-то особенность?

Comment: Какой результат Вам кажется неожиданным и почему?

Comment: Код не много изменил, изначально не коректно написал. Извиняюсь!

Comment: Так в чем вы видите особенность? Что не так, как ожидалось?

Comment: a + b = 4_000_000_000 - если промежуточное значение соханяется в int, тогда будет потеря данных из-за переполнения, как происходит во втором варианте. Не могу понять почему разные ответы. Если значение промежуточное значение сохраняется не в int, тогда почему во втором выводе не 2_000_000_000?

Comment: @Константин, возможно, компилятор оптимизировал код `a+b - b` убрав `b` и оставив только `a`

Comment: В первом варианте тоже происходит переполнение. Сделайте ``System.out.println(a + b);``.

Comment: a+b (4_000_000_000) - переполнение - b = 2_000_000_000; Второй вариант: a+b (4_000_000_000) - переполнение / 2 = 2_000_000_000 - я ожидал такой ответ по анологии.

Comment: Никаких 4_000_000_000 в вычислениях никогда не появляется.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/812095/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-int-%D0%B2-java/812104#812104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакой особенности нет.

Результатом `a+b` является не 4_000_000_000, а -294967296. Делим результат на 2, получаем -147483648, как в вопросе.

От -294967296 отнимаем 2_000_000_000, получаем очередное переполнение и снова результат 2_000_000_000.

```
int a = 2_000_000_000;
int b = 2_000_000_000;
int c = -294967296; // = a + b
System.out.println(a + b);
System.out.println((a + b - b));
System.out.println((a + b)/2);
System.out.println(c - b);
System.out.println(c / 2);
```

Вывод:

```
-294967296 // a + b -> = c
2000000000 // a + b - b
-147483648 // (a + b) / 2
2000000000 // c - b -> = a + b - b
-147483648 // c / 2 -> = (a + b) / 2
```